# Cauchy Theorem: $f$ is analytic for $|z|<2$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ evaluate $I=\int_{|z|=1} (Re z+\alpha)\frac{f(z)}{z}dz.$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Suppose that $f$ is analytic for $|z|<2$ and $\alpha$ is a complex constant. 
Evaluate 
$$I=\int_{|z|=1} (Re z+\alpha)\frac{f(z)}{z}dz.$$

On $|z|=1$, $Re z=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$ so we can get $\frac{1}{2}\int_{|z|=1}(z^2+1+2\alpha z)\frac{f(z)}{z^2}dz$ in an attempt to get rid of $Re z$, but I do not know how to proceed from here. This is from a chapter on Cauchy's Theorem and I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm no master of complex variables, but I think multiplying things out will yield some results.

Comment: Use the linearity of the integral. What do Cauchy's theorems say about $$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{f(z)}{z^k}\,dz\:?$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Cauchy's Theorem states that if $f(z)$ is analytic in a simply connected domain $D$ and $C$ is a closed contour lying in $D$, then $\int_C f(z)dz=0$. Here, $f(z)/z^k$ is not analytic in a simply connected domain, so how can we apply the theorem?

Comment: That's one of the theorems, that deals with the $z^2$ in the parenthesis. Haven't you yet learned the integral formula? That would deal with the remaining two terms in the parenthesis.

Comment: I am unsure about that form of $\text{Re}(z)$. The function $f(z) = \text{Re}(z)$ fails to be analytic everywhere while $z+ z^{-1}$ only fails to be analytic at $z = 0$.

Comment: @SZN That form for $\operatorname{Re} z$ is valid on the unit circle (and only there).

Comment: @DanielFischer The version of the Cauchy Theorem you refer to is in the next Chapter, but I guess this exercise was meant to use that one.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes. I do see this now. Yet the CR equations still fail, which typically implies the function is not analytic. Perhaps this is because the unit circle is not open in the usual topology on $\mathbb{C}$? I am actually a bit confused here myself.

Comment: Maybe. Alternatively, if you already know about that, one can expand $f$ into its power series (centred at $0$), and interchange summation and integration (legitimate because the series converges uniformly on $\lvert z\rvert = 1$). The integral $\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} z^m\,dz$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ can easily be explicitly evaluated. If that also isn't yet available, things get difficult.

Comment: @SZN Yes, the unit circle having empty interior makes it possible that the nowhere complex differentiable function $\operatorname{Re}$ agrees with a complex differentiable function _on the unit circle_.

Comment: @SZN - $\int_{|z|=1} (Re z+\alpha)\frac{f(z)}{z}dz$ is just the integral of a continuous function defined on a finite curve along that curve. It is well-defined regardless of analyticity of the function. Now this non-analytic function happens to coincide with an analytic one on the curve. The integral value is determined completely by the values of the function on that curve, so the two functions must have the same integral. So if we find the integral of that analytic function, we have also found the integral of the non-analytic one.